# Picker while in Landscape

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, picker, native-base

Hello i hope someone can help me, since i have been searching in the internet for some time now without any result and i am a beginner in react. Currently i am working on a react-native App.

The Problem is in the App i am using Native-Base and i tried to implement a Picker. But i realized that when the Device is in Landscape and i'm using the Picker. The Device will change back to Portrait even if it's still rotated.

[Here is an example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qskhJ.gif)

And i have the following code

```
export default class ChoosePlatformLanguage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lang: "",
        platform: ""
    };
  }
  _setLanguage(value) {
    this.setState({ lang: value });
  }
  _setPlatform(value) {
    this.setState({ platform: value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Left />
                <Body>
                  <Title>Platform & Sprache</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right />
            </Header>
            <View>
                <View>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Text>Platform</Text>
                        <Picker
                            supportedOrientations={['portrait', 'landscape']}
                            placeholder="Platform"
                            selectedValue={this.state.platform}
                            onValueChange={this._setPlatform}
                        >
                            <Item label={'Deutschland'} value={'de'} />
                            <Item label={'Österreich'} value={'at'} />
                        </Picker>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Text>Sprache</Text>
                        <Picker
                            supportedOrientations={['portrait', 'landscape']}
                            placeholder="Language"
                            selectedValue={this.state.lang}
                            onValueChange={this._setLanguage}
                        >
                            <Item label={'Deutsch'} value={'de'} />
                            <Item label={'English'} value={'en'} />
                        </Picker>
                    </ListItem>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text>Bestätigen</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```